# Best way to get first n characters of the string in Python

Tags: python, slice

I need to get first **n** characters of the string of **x** characters, where `n = x - len(endstring)` and `endstring` can have any number of characters from 0 to **x**.

Is there cleaner and better performance-wise way to do it in Python beside:

```
string[:len(string) - len(endstring)]
```

?

Main point is that `len(string)` looks a little redundant, but to account for  `endstring` of 0 characters it seemed as the "smoothest" solution?

Comment: What do you mean redundant? string and endstring are different variables, no?

Comment: @cricket_007 I think he says redundant because he is getting his string from `string`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do `string[:-len(endstring) or None]` instead.

Comment: Fails for the case `endstring = ''`.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that @Rob.  I have fixed it so that it won't.

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected. Not sure which is more python style, but I like your way better.